# MonoDevelop's debugger and xterm/gnome-terminal

Tags: monodevelop, gnome-terminal, xubuntu, xfce

I am using Xubuntu 15.04. I tried to run a basic console app using MonoDevelop, the latest one. I did a new project and this appears when I try to debug it:

> Could not connect to the debugger

I googled for answers and I found out that there is a problem with the gnome-terminal, that it no longer accepts the `--disable-factory` argument and something about unchecking the "Run on external console". I unchecked that and when I press to run, it closed it immediately.

Comment: what version of monodevelop is this?

Comment: The last one available on their website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Try executing MonoDevelop as `sudo`</del>

<del>$ sudo monodevelop</del>

<del>It takes Xterm as output terminal emulator.</del>

**EDIT**

Run Monodevelop as root can be a BIG mistake.

Best way is to write an script that unsets GNOME desktop session and run monodevelop, as Oskar says.

Try this one (copy and paste it on vim/nano and save as *monodevelop.sh*)

```
#!/bin/bash
unset GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
monodevelop
```

Put it on your home (for example) and give it execution permissions:

```
chmod +x ./monodevelop.sh
```

When you want to run it, execute `./monodevelop.sh`. Or you can add it as GNOME shell application [following this guide](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en).

Comment: Do NOT do this. Blindly running the IDE with full administrative permissions is not a good solution. Use `unset GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID; monodevelop` instead. No need for root access.

Comment: Agree. Best way is to write a script that unsets GNOME desktop session and run monodevelop.

Comment: For KDE, unset `KDE_SESSION_VERSION`, for Mate - `MATE_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID`.

Comment: Is there any way to get which DE am I using at this moment via command line? It would be nice to write an _universal script_ to solve this bug.